# can someone explain why I cannot able to get the last result for this code

Tags: python

Problem
Chef participated in a contest and got a rank XX.

Chef is trying to find his name in the ranklist but there are too many pages.

Each page consists of 2525 participants. Chef wants to find the exact page number which contains his name.
Help Chef find the page number.

Input Format
The first line of input will contain a single integer TT, denoting the number of test cases.
Each test case consists of a single integer XX - denoting the rank of Chef.
Output Format
For each test case, output the page number of the ranklist containing Chef's name.

test case:

input:

4
1
34
150
74

output:

1
2
6
3

Explanation:
Test case 1: Since each page has 25 participants, the first page has participants with rank 1 to 25. Thus, Chef can find his name in page number 1.

Test case 2: Since each page has 25 participants, the first page has participants with rank 1 to 25 and the second page has participants with rank 26 to 50. Thus, Chef can find his name in page number 2.

Test case 3: Chef will find his name in page number 6. The sixth page consists of participants with ranks 126 to 150.

Test case 4: Chef will find his name in page number 3. The third page consists of participants with ranks 51 to 75.

```
arr = []
for i in range(x):
    m = int(input())
    arr.append(m)

times = 1

res = 25

end = 25
stt = 0

for i in arr:
    
    f = True
    while f:
        if i > stt and i < end+1:
            f = False
            print(times)
        else:
            times += 1
            stt = end 
            end = res * times
```

for my code I'm getting output as

1
2
6

that's it, not able to get the answer for 74

Comment: you can use `while True: ... break` instead of variable `f`, but that won't fix the problem

Comment: It may be because `times = 1` should be inside the for loop and resets with every run of the for loop unlike where it is currently being constantly updated

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

arr = [4,34,150,74]
result = (np.array(arr)-1)//25 + 1
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I think is because 'stt' and 'end' has don't be reset in every new iteration. So, when you calculete the third page (times = 6), you are getting stt = 150 and end = 175, means that for the last case you are enter in a infiny loop.

Only has to reset stt and end for every case.

Comment: so how do I fix that, like how I'm supposed to reset the variable globally?

Comment: In the first loop, just above f = True. So, everytime you calculate the times with the same conditions.